# Making email field required in php

Tags: php, email, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a php script for the capture of a name and email address for a mailing list. If possible could someone please offer some adivce on how to make the email and name fields as required, so user is forced to input their name and email into form fields.

Again much appreciated for any help !!

The following is the php code being used for the form

```
<?php
$sendTo = "info@mail.com";
$subject = "website email enquiry";

$headers = "From: " . $_POST["firstName"] ." ". $_POST["lastname"] . "<" . $_POST["email"] .">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-path: " . $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Just need to validate if the fields are `empty` or not. If fields are empty, then redirect again to the same page.

Comment: `if (empty($_POST['email'])) ...`

Comment: thank you so much for the reply ! How do I go about validating the fields ? Sorry Im really new to php

Answer (score 1):

You have to check values of `$_POST['firstname']`, `$_POST['lastname']` and `$_POST['email']`

For the the name, you can check it with :

[empty()](http://php.net//manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if ( empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['lastname']) )
  // catch error
```

You can also, use [strlen()](http://php.net//manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to check string size and not validate a name with only 1 character length.

For email, you can check it with :

[filter validate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

```
if ( !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
  // catch error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //Your code
} else {
    //Show your errors
}
```

The above code will validate the contents of your e-mail post variable to be a valid email address.

Comment: thank you so very much and sorry where would I add this code among the php of my form ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best way to do this in PHP.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
//Perform action
}
else{
echo "Please type in your email";
}
?>`
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do this in PHP anymore. In your form where you have your email filed/textbox, just insert required and type as email then the form won't submit unless this fill contains a valid email address.

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required value="<? echo $email; ?>" placeholder="example@fordberg.com"/>
```

That should do the trick. HTML5 Baby!

Comment: The problem with this in my opinion is that it is not server side validation, meaning i can use my firebug or chrome developer tool to remove the required part of the form, and i'll still be able to post it

Comment: You're right! I've answered again with a PHP solution.